# Can I run a nested build.dart from its location instead of project root?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

Dart Editor runs build.dart from the root of the project. However, I have a build.dart file in a subdirectory. The default behavior of Dart Editor breaks this build.dart file, because the paths in the file are relative to build.dart.

My project looks like this:

```
apps/
  app1/
    build.dart
  app2/
    build.dart
```

I have opened `apps` in my Editor. I am trying to run apps/app1/build.dart from within `apps/app1` but Editor is running from `apps`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: In WebStorm you can setup a watcher, and let it run a script. I think it would solve that issue but I haven't played much time with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yay, this bug has been fixed. Dart Editor will now run `build.dart` from its directory.

Answer (score 0):

*Hrm... I wonder what project you might be working on that has a lot of build.dart files within...*

**Short answer: no.**

As of posting, [this is an open bug](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=9945). Please star it!

See also [this discussion.](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/editor/vkVnHMNix_Y)